# Can you apply a for loop in a sapply function using the argument in sapply?

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I am basically altering an existing long, rather complicated code, to include new parameters and I want to add a for loop in an existing sapply function, but the for loop uses an argument from sapply.

*(see code below)*

ld is a character string of the list of directories, so in the current code it is applying a function to each directory one by one (I just used .... to simplify it).

Now I use list.dirs to introduce td, which is a list of the subdirectories inside each ld (it works,I checked for a single folder). I am trying make a for loop which loops through the tds for a given ld. 
E.g. once working on ld[1], I want it identify the subfolders in this folder only, save them as a character string and apply another function (in the for loop) to each of these subfolders. 
Then it moves to the second folder in the ld strings and applies the function to each subfolder there and so on.

```
sapply(file.path(ld), function(folder){ 

....

td = list.dirs(ld, recursive = FALSE)  
      for (j in td){
           .........
  }
}
```

I get the error:

*Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument*

I put a couple of print functions to see what happens and I see that within sapply:
***td = list.dirs(ld, recursive = FALSE)*** 
lists **all** the subfolders in **all** of the ld folders, not only the current one. 
Also, immediately after I introduce the for loop, I printed out td[j], which gives NA.

Now is the time to say I never figured out how to use apply family of functions which is probably why I can't get this to work, I assume they work as a regular loop while this isn't the case. Also it would be easier to make a nested for loop I guess, but before I do it, I am trying to make minimal changes to the current code in case I mess it up, since I am very beginner in programming..

I hope this is clear, any help with be appreciated!

Comment: `td = list.dirs(folder, recursive = FALSE)`?

Comment: Cheers, this solved the first problem! But when I try to access td in the for loop (i.e. td[1], it again gives NA.

Comment: PS accessing td[1] on its own works fine, it shows the first subdirectory.

Comment: I'm silly, it should be j on its own, because it's a character vector (?), I guess this part is sorted, thank you loads, I'll set this question as solved :)